# Find AggregateResult Fields Dynamically

Tags: aggregate, dynamic

I ran across some code a while back to find fields within an AggregateResult dynamically to do some processing irregardless of what was in it.

```
AggregateResult results = [SELECT COUNT_DISTINCT(ParentId) FROM Account];
Set<String> aggregateColumns = new Set<String>();
String aggregateString = String.valueOf(results).removeStart('AggregateResult:').removeStart('{').removeEnd('}');

List<String> aggregateResultList = aggregateString.split(', ', 0);
for (string pair : aggregateResultList)
    if(String.isNotEmpty(pair) && pair.indexOf('=') > 0) 
    {
        List<String> keyAndValue = pair.split('=', -2);
        if (keyAndValue.size() > 0 && String.isNotEmpty(keyAndValue[0]))
            myColumns.add(keyAndValue[0]);
    }
```

This worked, but I was surprised he resorted to String parsing to find the value.

I thought of using JSON parsing, however, I kept running into exceptions when I tried to convert the AggregateResult to a Map of some sort. I later found out that AggregateResult's, since they are considered sObjects, are impossible to parse that way.

So, is there an easy way to find the AggregateResult fields dynamically?

Comment: You should post what you had tried. It's not really fair game to post questions without example code.

Comment: I could post a link to the blog that has the actual code there. I just felt weird about it.

Comment: It's kind of against the SFSE guidelines to not share what you have tried so far, so without it, I am voting this question be closed.

Comment: I went and added the code that I found from the blog, I modified it slightly, but it retains the same structure. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Believe it or not, I was very, very close. `JSON.deserialize` may not be able to provide me a `Map`, but `JSON.deserializeUntyped` can.

Once I found out I could utilize that, I came up with the following code:

```
AggregateResult results = [SELECT COUNT_DISTINCT(ParentId) FROM Account];
Map<String, Object> aggregateResultMap = 
   (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(JSON.serialize(results));
aggregateResultMap.remove('attributes');
```

I made sure to add the line `aggregateResultMap.remove('attributes')` to remove any class information.   From  the map, I can simply call `aggregateResultMap.keySet()` to provide the list of fields used and so solve the "Find AggregateResult Fields Dynamically" problem.

**Break-down**
We can easily serialize our data by calling the `JSON.serailize` method. Turning it into a string. So the following code:

```
AggregateResult results = [SELECT COUNT_DISTINCT(ParentId) FROM Account];
System.Debug(LoggingLevel.Info, JSON.serialize(results));
```

Will produce a String like this:

> {"attributes":{"type":"AggregateResult"},"expr0":0}

However, using `JSON.serialize won't work:

```
Map<String, Object> aggregateResultMap = 
   (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserialize(JSON.serialize(results), Map<String, Object>.class);
```

since it throws the following Exception:

> System.JSONException: Apex Type unsupported in JSON: Object

I also tried this:

```
Map<String, String> aggregateResultMap = 
   (Map<String, String>)JSON.deserialize(JSON.serialize(results), Map<String, String>.class);
```

Which threw the following Exception:

> System.JSONException: Illegal value for primitive

That's why I used `JSON.deserializeUntyped`.

Using my answer, above:

*aggregateResultMap produces:*

> {expr0=0}

*aggregateResultMap.keySet() produces:*

> {expr0}

Comment: Could you pls show the sample o/p of aggregateResultMap.keySet() ? Just curious.

Comment: Added it for you.